# In python, how to divide two lists of lists by each other?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists like so

```
volB = [(Tarp, 3440, 7123), (Greg, 82, 1083)]
```

and

```
# 500B = [(Tarp, 85, 203), (Greg, 913, 234)]
B500 = [(Tarp, 85, 203), (Greg, 913, 234)]
```

I want to divide the second elements by each other. (In this case, I'd want to divide 3440 by 85, 82 by 913, and so on. Thanks for the help?

Comment: Should those tuples perhaps be objects? Or at least a NamedTuple? It seems like they are a little too meaningful..

Comment: If you want help with Python, show us python, not something that looks vaguely like Python.

Comment: `500B` is not a valid identifier in Python.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: It hurt my eyes as well. Fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
from __future__ import division
quotients = [x[1] / y[1] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Care to elaborate slightly more of `from __future__ import division` to OP? Thanks

Comment: The `from __future__ import division`  says to use the Py3k definition of division instead of the Py2k definition (assuming you're using Py2k; in Py3k, the import is a no-op).  In Py2k, integer division is truncating, like it is in C, so that 82/913 = 0.  In Py3k, integer division does a floating-point division, so that 82/913 = 0.08981380065717415.

Comment: Thanks. Was using py2k and it kept turning out 0... now I know why!

Comment: The only thing i can add is that would be better to sort list in case of using zip since if initial lists are not sorted than this solution will not work properly

Answer (score -1):

OR not so beatiful but:

```
lA = [('A',123,11),('B', 1, 11)]
lB = [('B',12,11),('A', 1, 11)]

res = {}

for x,y,z in (lA+lB):
    if not x in res:
        res[x] = y
        continue
    res[x] = res[x] / (y * 1.0)
```

Edited as per comment to be more pythonic (note that Sven's solution has been selected as base):

```
from operator import itemgetter

lA = [('A',123,11),('B', 1, 11)]
lB = [('B',12,11),('A', 1, 11)]

[float(x[1])/float(y[1]) for x,y in zip(sorted(lA,key=itemgetter(0)), sorted(lB,key=itemgetter(0)))]
```

Comment: Ugh.  This is incredibly unpythonic, and I can't even tell if it works or not.

Comment: I checked it several times and it works, it works even if lists aren't sorted. Also there was nothing about more/less pythonic in this question.